# Problem with dependency property

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, static

I am trying to create a static property, and the only way I could find to do it, is using DependencyProperty.

I have created the following fields in my class :

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty UnreadMessagesProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("UnreadMessages", typeof(int), typeof(ErrorLog));

    public int UnreadMessages
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)GetValue(ErrorLog.UnreadMessagesProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ErrorLog.UnreadMessagesProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

And this compiles fine, but when I try to set the initial value of UnreadMessages in the contructor to 0 using the following code:

```
public ErrorLog()
{
    this.UnreadMessages = 0;
}
```

I get the following exception

```
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.  
Error at object 'System.Windows.Data.Binding' in markup file 'Dashboard;component/main.xaml'.
```

And the Inner Exception message is below:

```
Value cannot be null.    
Parameter name: dp
```

And the Full Stack Trace of the inner exception:

```
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetupPropertyChange(DependencyProperty dp)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
   at Dashboard.ErrorLog.set_UnreadMessages(Int32 value) in ErrorLog.xaml.cs:line 67
   at Dashboard.ErrorLog..ctor() in ErrorLog.xaml.cs:line 97
   at Dashboard.ErrorLog..cctor() in ErrorLog.xaml.cs:line 33
```

Singleton Instance Approach code:

```
public static readonly ErrorLog Instance = new ErrorLog();
```

What I am trying to do, is have a static UnreadMessages property which I can bind to in my Main class so I can display if there are any unread error messages that the user needs to be made aware of.

I tried using a singleton approach but I cannot seem to be able to bind to ErrorLog.Instance.UnreadMessages.

Could anyone help me out?

Comment: How do you bind this property in Dashboard;component/main.xaml?

Comment: Text="{Binding Source={x:Static local:ErrorLog.Instance}, Path=UnreadMessages}"

"local" is decalred as : xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Dashboard"

Comment: Hm... Still fill like we are missing something. Could you please show  ErrorLog.xaml.cs:line 73, and bigger stack trace? Also please show how do you get error log instance.

Comment: feel :) Not fill :). Gosh. Sorry :)

Comment: {x: Static } is used for accessing static properties and UnreadMessages is not static. But you'll get this error later. First, there is the issue of the DP not being created.

Comment: @Timores, ErrorLog.Instance seems to be static.

Comment: Just added the full stack, and Insance code. See original question. (up votes for taking interest in the question and helping me)

Comment: I copy/pasted the code in a WPF app and had no problem. Like Anvaka wrote, we need more info on the app.

Comment: @Anvaka, yes Instance is static, but {x: Static} is used to access a static field/property and UnreadMessages is not.
(btw, did you know that you can edit your own comments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could reproduce the problem.
In your ErrorLog class, I guess you have:

```
public static readonly ErrorLog Instance = new ErrorLog();
public static readonly DependencyProperty UnreadMessagesProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("UnreadMessages", typeof(int), typeof(ErrorLog));
```

Change it to:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty UnreadMessagesProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("UnreadMessages", typeof(int), typeof(ErrorLog));
public static readonly ErrorLog Instance = new ErrorLog();
```

The order is simply reversed.
Both elements are static and reference the same types, so .NET cannot order it. In the first case, the instance is created and the DP is used before being instantiated.

You could avoid this problem by specifying a default value when creating the DP.

On a 2nd note, the XAML is wrong. {x: Static } expects a type name as first parameter, not an instance. And UnreadMessages is not static, the DP is.
Do not use DPs to create static properties.

If you need a static property, just declare one in your code-behind/data context class and bind it with {x: Static}.

Comment: Thanks a million! Didnt think this would make a difference!

Comment: By the way, regarding your 2nd note. When I create a static property, I cannot implement NotifyPropertyChanged which ends up in my UI not being updated as this property changed. Any suggestion

Comment: I was afraid you'd ask this :-)
Have a look at: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/b42027ab-07be-47a1-889a-a930d19fc4a5/ the last entry is an interesting solution, if it suits your needs.